# How can you check whether method was inlined?

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I just read a blog which says *"...methods that couldn’t be inlined previously because of other criteria are still not inlined. I checked the following, and neither of these methods was inlined..."*

I cant reach the author and also I thought it might be interesting for SO users too. So I'd like to ask:

**How can you check if a method was in fact inlined (or not)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2008/08/19/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question.aspx) entry about inlining states, among other interesting things:

> Steven did this by throwing an exception and then programmatically
>   inspecting the stack trace associated with the exception.    This
>   makes sense when you are trying to automate the analysis, but for
>   simple one-off cases, it is simpler and more powerful to simply look
>   at the native instructions.  See [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2006/02/20/535807.aspx) for details on how to using
>   Visual Studio.

ie: apparently for casual research just reading what's actually getting executed is the way to go.

Comment: > just reading what's actually getting executed - I would think the same.. but question here is - **can you guarantee JIT will not optimise it differently in normal run-time** (in contrast to running under VS host)?

Comment: P.S. the comment above is rethoric question. You cant guarantee. Moreover I can almost guarantee it will change if you run it stand-alone.

Comment: @Bobb actually I think that's seriously bad news, because it will seriously hinder your abilities to debug nasty and obscure problems...

Comment: I am doing loads of benchmarking of different piece of code. And I can tell you for sure if you run time-sensitive test from inside VS and stand-alone you will always have different results... I am not VS guru and never was interested. So I cant explain why but thats the fact. JIT uses different strategies obviously. P.S. I dont think this is bad news. it works fine if you know what you do... I am sure this is described somewhere by Microsoft. People just dont bother to read.